# How do I count the occurrences of NOT NULL fields in a record

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to count the number of times a record field has a value so that I can report that number later in the application.

I am finding several answers with various approaches using COUNT and GROUP BY but the results are all sums of the total occurrences for the entire table.

I am trying to limit the count to each record.

```
Table Example:
COL-1     COL-2     COL-3     COL-4   
VALUE               VALUE
          VALUE               VALUE
VALUE               VALUE     VALUE
VALUE
```

I need to count the fields of each record for the number of times a value appears.

Something similar to:

```
Result Concept:
COL-1     COL-2     COL-3     COL-4     Occurrences
VALUE               VALUE                   2
          VALUE               VALUE         2
VALUE               VALUE     VALUE         3
VALUE                                       1
```

Clarification:
I do not actually need to list the columns and values in the result.  I only need the accurate count for each record.
I just wanted to illustrate the relationship between the "occurrences-value" and the record values in my question.

Thank you for all suggestions and input.

Comment: What value stands for? A count is done by rows, not columns, to do what you want a little trick need to be applied. So is value a number that you want to sum or just any present value that if it is present it means 1 in occurrence?

Comment: And another question, the final value is the sum of occurrences or the list of occurrences?

Comment: If you pivot the columns into rows, you can use a regular `count` on them.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `case`:

```
select t.*,
       ( (case when col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col4 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as occurrences
from t;
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!!

Now I'm finding that I am not sure how to associate that value with it's record.

Inside a stored procedure I am trying to update a "total-count" field in a separate table with that occurrences value.

It seems like a Cursor should be able to make the value available to the procedure but again I'm stuck on how to properly align the primary and foreign key's correctly in this case.

I would be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: @LearnsWhileDoing . . . I would suggest that you ask another question and be clear that you want to *update* the table.  This one is pretty clearly about returning the results as a query.

Answer (score 0):

Or decode ;)

```
select t.*, DECODE(col1,null,0,1)+DECODE(col2,null,0,1)+
            DECODE(col3,null,0,1)+DECODE(col4,null,0,1) cnt
from my_table t
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the dynamic SQL without listing all column names

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tbl VARCHAR(100)

SET @tbl = 'sampletable' -- put your table name here

SET @sql = 'SELECT *, ' 

SELECT @sql = @sql + '(CASE WHEN ' + cols.name + ' IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ' + '+'
  FROM sys.columns cols
 WHERE cols.object_id = object_id(@tbl); 

SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1)
SET @sql = @sql + ' AS occurrences FROM ' + @tbl

EXEC(@sql)
```